# How to upload html email template data through ajax

Tags: php, html, laravel, email

I'm trying to edit the content of an email template from database and sending it to my users. Now whenever i click on send button only half of of the html email content is sent to the user email address.

Here is my code

```
$this->validate($request, [
            'to' => 'required|email',
            'contents' => 'required',
            'subject'=> 'required'
        ]);

        $data = [
            'to_user' => $request->to,
            'content' => $request->contents,
            'type' => 'email'
        ];
        $unique = str_random(6) . '-'.str_random(5);

         File::put("/var/www/resources/views/mails/" . $unique.".blade.php", $request->contents);

        $datas = [
            'from' => 'support@example.com',
            'from_name' => 'Example',
            'reply_to' => 'support@example.com',
            'reply_to_name'=> 'Example Support Team',
            'subject'=> $request->subject,
            'type' => 'email',
            'code' => $unique
        ];
        \App\DeliveryLog::create($data);

        Mail::to($request->to)->send(new DeliveryMail($datas));
```

Here is the screenshot of Request being sent to controller.
[Check Screenshot](https://ibb.co/g1WiSf) !

Here is the Ajax code

```
$('.sendEmail').on('click', function () {
            email = $('#semail').val();
            subject = $('#subject').val();
            content = CKEDITOR.instances.CustomerEmailTemplate_content.getData();
            $(".sendEmail").text("Sending... Please wait.");
            $('.sendEmail').prop('disabled', true);

            request = $.ajax({
                url: "/ajax/send/email",
                type: "post",
                data: "to=" + email + "&subject=" + subject + "&contents=" + content + "&_token=" + $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
            });

            // Callback handler that will be called on success
            request.done(function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                // Log a message to the console
                if (response.result === "success") {

                    iziToast.success({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: 'Email Sent Successfully.',
                        position: 'topRight',
                        timeout: '10000',
                        pauseOnHover: true,
                    });
                } else {
                    iziToast.warning({
                        title: 'Success',
                        message: response.message,
                        position: 'topRight',
                        timeout: '10000',
                        pauseOnHover: true,
                    });
                }

            });

            // Callback handler that will be called on failure
            request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                // Log the error to the console
                console.error(
                    "The following error occurred: " +
                    textStatus, errorThrown
                );
            });

            // Callback handler that will be called regardless
            // if the request failed or succeeded
            request.always(function () {
                $(".sendEmail").text("Send Email");
                $('.sendEmail').prop('disabled', false);

            });

        });
```

I'm not receiving any error but only half email is being stored.

Answer (score 1):

That's because your HTML content is being interpreted as many post fields, your screenshot shows a property called subject, other contents, and then one called `<html>`, `<head>`, and so on. A possible solution is to serialize your template before sending it via HTTP request and then unserialize it.